# Android people app - what selection used to query contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm using the following cursor

```
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
         ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,        
         CONTACTS_PROJECTION,
         ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1", 
         null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
```

This works for retrieving a list of contacts but obviously only where they have a phone number. If I try removing the HAS PHONE NUMBER selection then the list that I get back is huge with 1000's and 1000's of contacts. I'm looking to get back the same list of contacts from my cursor that the "people" app does but I can't work out what selection they are using. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, to answer my own question after doing some digging. instead of the phone number section this seems to work:

```
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
     ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,        
     CONTACTS_PROJECTION,
     ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + "=1", 
     null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
```